# Группировка по нескольким столбцам с выдачей частоты Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть исходная таблица:

```
А   Б
1   1
1   1
1   2
2   2
2   3
3   3
3   4
3   1
```

Необходимо взять все уникальные значения из столбца `А`, потом посмотреть частоту встречаемости уникальных значений из `Б`. И в третьем столбце `В` вывести результат.

Примерно так:

```
А   Б   В
1   1   2
1   2   1
2   2   1
2   3   1
3   3   1
3   4   1
3   1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант, похожий на решение @splash58:

```
In [20]: df.groupby(list(df)).size().reset_index(name="B")
Out[20]:
   А  Б  B
0  1  1  2
1  1  2  1
2  2  2  1
3  2  3  1
4  3  1  1
5  3  3  1
6  3  4  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Группировка сама по себе соберет уникальные значения

```
df.groupby(df.columns.to_list()).agg(В=('Б','count')).reset_index()

   А  Б  В
0  1  1  2
1  1  2  1
2  2  2  1
3  2  3  1
4  3  1  1
5  3  3  1
6  3  4  1
```

Comment: index object has no attribute 'to list' выдает

Comment: в моей версии не выдает, но поставьте явно ['А','Б'] Мне просто было лень разбираться, на русском у вас A или на английском :)